# Не работает dp.callback_query_handler

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Я не могу разобраться, почему после нажатия на кнопки button1 и button2 ничего не происходит в боте, в логах и в консоли. Принт тоже ничего не выводит. Вроде указываю callback_data, и по ней же в callback_query_handler пытаюсь поймать событие, но ощущение, что не работает совсем. Пытался так же запустить на сервере в облаке результат тот же.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

import PW

API_TOKEN = PW.token

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)



@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Yes', callback_data='1')
    button2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='No', callback_data='2')
    ikb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    ikb.add(button1)
    ikb.add(button2)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Ready?', reply_markup=ikb)


@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def some_callback_handler(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    print(callback_query)
    if callback_query.data == '1':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id, text='Let\'s start')
    await callback_query.answer(text='Bye')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp, skip_updates=True)
```

[image: telegram screen]

Comment: как минимум у вас должна вылезать ошибка на `ikb.add(button2)`, потому что `button2` у вас не существует. Во всем остальном код рабочий. Можно конечно и `if callback_query.data == '1'` убрать, т.к. вы и так попали в этот хэндлер при `callback_data='1'`

Comment: @ZxNuClear это я ошибся при написании вопроса, я пробовал с двумя кнопками и с одной. Не работает. Даже выводил принтом call back в функции, ничего не выводится. Ощущение, что хендлер не видит call back. Самое интересное делал всё по видео с YouTube, где этот код работает. Может дело не в коде, а в чём-то другом?

Comment: как я писал ранее - тот кусок кода, который вы привели в вопросе - рабочий. Возможно проблема в другой части. Нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1532291/edit) под вопросом и приложите весь код, предварительно убрав из него Token

Comment: Поменяйте этот параметр `chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id` на `callback_query.message.chat.id`

Comment: @KJlUK_KJIAK если вывести результат через `print(callback_query.from_user.id, callback_query.message.chat.id)`, то получим один и тот же ID, так что проблема не в этом

Comment: @ZxNuClear добавил полностью код, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @KJlUK_KJIAK добавил полный код, спасибо за помощь, пробовал сделать print(callback_query.from_user.id, callback_query.message.chat.id) ничего не происходит

Comment: @NikPetrov ваш код полностью рабочий. При нажатии на `Yes` бот выдет `Let's start` и потом уведомление `Bye`. При нажатии на `No` только уведомление `Bye`. Вероятно вы просто ожидаете другого поведения от бота?

Comment: @ZxNuClear я как раз это и жду, честное слово, я когда его запускаю ввожу команду /start, появляется сообщение Ready? и две кнопки, я тыкаю кнопки и у кнопок появляются часики, и все.... Я тоже понимаю, что код полностью рабочий написан, поэтому сюда и пришел с вопросом. Использую python3.10 на линуксе, но поидеи должно все работать

Comment: @ZxNuClear прикрепил скрин

Comment: Вы же знаете, что данное действие пришлет Вам не сообщение `await callback_query.answer(text='Bye')`? Что это не то же самое, что `message.answer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пересоздал бота в телеграмме все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю пойти от простого. Вот вам полностью рабочая и упрощенная реализация вашего кода:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton


bot = Bot(token='TOKEN')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Yes', callback_data='1')
    button2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='No', callback_data='2')
    ikb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    ikb.add(button1).add(button2)
    await message.answer('Ready?', reply_markup=ikb)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='1')
async def some_callback_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer('Let\'s start')


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='2')
async def some_callback_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer('Bye')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Если он у вас не будет работать, то нужно искать проблему не там, где вы ее ищите, т.к. и ваш код, как я писал уже - полностью рабочий

Comment: Подумал, что написал автор ... еб**ть я молодец ))

Answer (score 0):

В нем заменили  `await callback_query.answer(text='Bye')` ->  `await call.message.answer('Bye')`
[image: Код полностью исправен тот что в ответах]

Comment: @ZxNuClear запустил ваш код,  не работает все равно, и на другой машине запустил тоже не работает. Даже разные машины не спасают, не могу даже предположить в чем проблема.

Comment: Я заметил, что есть настроки бота в телеге, может там что нужно поменять?

Comment: создайте нового бота...У меня этот бот сделан для теста, там ничего не настроено

Comment: Блин просто создал нового бота и заработало, спасибо, ребят как могу вам рейтинг поднять? куда тыкать?)

Comment: приймеш ответы как верные и рейтинг апнется